# Conversion failed when converting date and / or time when creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'am making a table with a char, varchar and date. I got an error message saying "Conversion failed when converting date and / or time". If anyone can help me fix, this you got sincere thank you. :D

this is my code for creating and inserting data on my table:

```
Create table Employee
(EMP_NUM  char(3), 
EMP_LNAME varchar(15), 
EMP_FNAME varchar(15), 
EMP_INITIAL char(1), 
EMP_HIREDATE date, 
JOB_CODE char (3), 
EMP_YEARS char(2))

Insert into Employee (EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, 
EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE)
Values (101, 'News', 'John', 'G','08-Nov-00', 502),
(102, 'Senior', 'David', 'H','12-Jul-89', 501),
(103, 'Arbough', 'June', 'E','01-Dec-96', 500),
(104, 'Ramoras', 'Anne', 'K','15-Nov-87', 501),
(105, 'Johnson', 'Alice', 'k','01-Feb-93', 502),
(106, 'Smithfield', 'William', null, '22-Jun-04', 500),
(107, 'Alonzo', 'Maria', 'D','10-Oct-93', 500),
(108, 'Washington', 'Ralph', 'B', '22-Aug-91',501),
(109, 'Smith', 'Larry', 'W', '18-Jul-97', 501),
(110, 'Olenko', 'Gerald', 'A', '11-Dec-95', 505),
(111, 'Wabash', 'Geoff', 'B', '04-Apr-91', 506),
(112, 'Smithson', 'Darlene', 'M', '23-Oct-94', 507),
(113, 'Joenbrood', 'Delbert', 'K', '15-ov-96', 508),
(114, 'Jones', 'Annelise', null, '20-Aug-93', 508),
(115, 'Bawangi', 'Travis', 'B','25-Jan-92', 501),
(116, 'Pratt', 'Gerald', 'L','05-Mar-97', 510),
(117, 'Williamson', 'Angie', 'M', '19-Jun-96', 509),
(118, 'Frommer', 'james', 'J','04-Jan-05', 510);
```

and this is the complete message result :

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CONVERSION for EMP_HIREDATE column for date  :

```
For ex : 

SELECT CAST('18-Jul-97' AS DATE)

In your query :

Insert into Employee (EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL, 
 EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE)
SELECT 101, 'News', 'John', 'G',CAST('08-Nov-00' AS DATE), 502
```